# CSS and styling the body: image background won't work

Tags: html, css

By some curse i cannot for the life of me get this simple css call working. here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<link href="css/stylesheet2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<title>Welcome.</title>

</head>
    <body>
       <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my stylesheet:

```
body {
    background-image:url(img/landscape.jpg');
}
```

the file is named correctly. when i assign a background-color tag to this stylesheet, i get the color for whatever i assigned. is there some rule that keeps the body from having an image background? This is absolutely incredible. HOW is this not working for me?

Comment: It seems you've missed the left single quote: `url('img/landscape.jpg');`

Comment: You're missing a quote in your css: url(img/landscape.jpg') must be url('img/landscape.jpg'). But I assume that's just a typo in SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the path relative to your css.  Since you have your css in a folder named "css" and your images in a folder named "images", you must tell the path to move out of the css folder and into the images folder.

```
body {
    background-image:url('../img/landscape.jpg');
}
```

Comment: We don't know anything about his folder structure. For all we know, he could have a folder `/css/img/`.

Comment: this appeared to have worked, jrod. thanks a ton, this was completely mystifying

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the opening quote in your URL:

```
body {
    background-image:url('img/landscape.jpg');
}
```

This should definitely work, provided, as you say, the file is named correctly and is in the location you say it is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not a copy-paste error, your CSS is invalid, as you're missing a matching `'`:

```
background-image: url('img/landscape.jpg');
```

Apart from this, you should check that the URI is correct and that the image is accessible.
And as a side note, your XHTML is invalid as well. Stick to HTML4.01/5 or write valid XHTML (and serve it as `aaplication/xhtml+xml`).